# Confusion regarding the incomplete elliptic integral of the first kind

Tags: special-functions, complex

I am trying to manipulate a conformal map from the half-plane to a square $z \rightarrow w(z)$ defined by:

$$ w(z) = \int \limits^{z} dx \frac{1}{\sqrt{(1-x^2)x}} = \sqrt{2} \; F\left(\sqrt{z+1},\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)$$

where $F$ is the incomplete elliptic integral of the first kind according to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz%E2%80%93Christoffel_mapping#Square).

My problem is that the incomplete elliptic integral built into *Mathematica* as `EllipticF` does not seem to behave like this function, as its derivative is not singular at $z=1$ as the formula is telling us.

Proof that the *Mathematica* derivative is finite:

```
D[EllipticF[Sqrt[x + 1], Sqrt[2]/2], x] /. x -> 1 // N
```

gives me

```
0.63491
```

I am very unfamiliar with these functions; is it a convention difference between the two?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

(I just knew someone would ask this someday...)

I had talked (ranted?) about this issue at some length [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/108659), so I'd like you to read that first. I'll just give an executive summary here: *Mathematica* uses the *parameter* convention, while the formula you found on Wikipedia is based on the *modulus* convention (quickly betrayed by the comma separating the two arguments).

In fact, even the convention in the first argument is different, so `EllipticF[]` is not exactly the *Mathematica* function you want. What you need here, in *Mathematica*'s convention, is denoted as `InverseJacobiSN[]`:

```
D[InverseJacobiSN[Sqrt[x + 1], 1/2], x] /. x -> 1 // FullSimplify
   ComplexInfinity
```

---

After looking through my Schwarz-Christoffel notes, I'm not sure where the Wikipedia formula was obtained. In any case, allow me to present a short demonstration of the conventional conformal mapping between the upper half plane and a rectangle (though I cheat here and use the inverse map, `JacobiSN[]`, in the following code):

```
a = 1/2; b = 1; (* 2 a × b rectangle *)
m = ModularLambda[I b/a];

{ParametricPlot[With[{w = JacobiSN[EllipticK[m] (u + I v)/a, m]},
                     {Re[w], Im[w]}], {u, -a, a}, {v, 0, 99 b/100},
                BoundaryStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[2], Mesh -> 15, 
                MeshShading -> {{Transparent}}, 
                MeshStyle -> {Directive[AbsoluteThickness[2], ColorData[97, 1]], 
                              Directive[AbsoluteThickness[2], ColorData[97, 2]]}, 
                PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {0, 10}}], 
 ParametricPlot[{u, v}, {u, -a, a}, {v, 0, 99 b/100}, 
                BoundaryStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[2], Mesh -> 15, 
                MeshShading -> {{Transparent}}, 
                MeshStyle -> {Directive[AbsoluteThickness[2], ColorData[97, 1]], 
                              Directive[AbsoluteThickness[2], ColorData[97, 2]]}]}
// GraphicsRow
```

[image: upper half-plane to rectangle map]

As a check of correctness, try restricting the range of `v` to `{0, b/2}`. The mapping on the left should yield a semicircular region with radius `m^(-1/4)`.

Comment: P.S. You'll want to use `ParametricPlot[]` to visualize conformal mappings.

Comment: @ J.M. how do you relate the integral w to the function InverseJacobiSN? Plotting them shows they are rather different.

Comment: @Dr. Hintze, due to branch cuts, things are a little murkier. In fact, the actual mapping function is something like `Sqrt[2] (EllipticK[1/2] - InverseJacobiSN[Sqrt[1 - x], 1/2])`.

Comment: @ J.M. In fact we have -Im[Sqrt[2] (EllipticK[1/2]-InverseJacobiSN[Sqrt[1-z],1/2])] = f for z>=1. Hence my function f gives the complete solution for the intergal w in terms of incomplete (F) and complete (K) elliptic integrals - as I said in my answer.

Comment: Well, the OP uses $1-x^2$, while you use $x^2-1$; maybe that explains the discrepancy, @Dr. Hintze?

Comment: Yes this is the obvious and trivial difference. I took the definition of Wikipedia which was quoted but not correctly reproduced in the OP. But, again, mathematica calculates the intergral exactly and in terms of the correct form of elliptic integrals.

Comment: Personally, @Dr. Hintze, I'm not fond of the form returned, but that might be just my bias. In particular, I don't quite like having the parameter be outside the range $[0,1)$, which is what *Mathematica* does by default since it's the "lazy" route. AGM-based methods for numerical evaluation tend to perform much better when the parameter is within the unit interval.

Comment: I agree. I also don't like the rather indirect argument ArcSin[1/Sqrt[z]]. There is a simpler example: (1) Integrate[1/Sqrt[a - x^2], x] -> -ArcTan[(x Sqrt[a - x^2])/(-a + x^2)] but (2) Integrate[1/Sqrt[1 - x^2], x] ->  ArcSin[x] where in (1) MMA makes an "unnecessary" complication.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30994/discussion-between-dr-wolfgang-hintze-and-j-m).

Answer (score 3):

I would prefer to have consistency within the framework of Mathematica and hence start off with the original definition of your function as an integral taken here between `1` and `z`:

```
f = 
 Integrate[1/Sqrt[x (x^2 - 1)], {x, 1, z}, Assumptions -> z > 1]

(*
Out[35]= -2 EllipticF[ArcSin[1/Sqrt[z]], -1] + 2 EllipticK[-1]
*)
```

This is obviously different from the result you quote from Wikipedia.
Hence the validity of the latter should be clarified first.

Comment: It seems that there's a confusion in the definitions, as J.M. has just pointed out.

Comment: [This](http://dlmf.nist.gov/19.7.E5) might be of interest.